# Multiple gulp src

Tags: gulp

How this task can be simplified?

```
const merge = require('merge-stream')
gulp.task('templates', ()=>{
    return merge(
        gulp.src('./src/dashboard/views/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('public/views/dashboard')),
        gulp.src('./src/core/views/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('public/views/core')),
        gulp.src('./src/auth/views/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('public/views/auth')),
        gulp.src('./src/templates/views/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('public/views/templates'))
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `public/views/` as the destination path and get rid of the `/views` part in your source paths:

- public/views/ + dashboard<strike>/views</strike> = public/views/dashboard
- public/views/ + core<strike>/views</strike> = public/views/core
- public/views/ + auth<strike>/views</strike> = public/auth/auth
- public/views/ + templates<strike>/views</strike> = public/auth/templates

You can use [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to do that:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('templates', ()=>{
  return gulp.src('./src/*/views/**/*')
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
      file.dirname = file.dirname.replace(/\/views/, '');
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/views/'));
});
```

There's also [`gulp-regex-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-regex-rename) which is shorter (never used that one, so I can't vouch for it):

```
var rename = require('gulp-regex-rename');

gulp.task('default', ()=>{
  return gulp.src('./src/*/views/**/*')
    .pipe(rename(/\/views/, ''))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/views/'));
});
```